# How to apply nested case when statements in the most efficient way possible in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case-when

I'm trying to select two columns from a join with three tables. Specifically, the first column is a rate which is computed as a subtraction between two columns if another column equals 1. The second column is a flag for how many times the txn_rate is not null. Am I doing the 'case when' statements in the most efficient way possible? Please see the code below (I masked the join logic to be simpler, since I don't think that matters too much)

One quick note: the logic I wanted to follow was create a flag and then sum the flag in a staging table (this is pre-staging). Is there a more efficient way to create a binary flag?

```
Select case when a.column = 1 then (b.column - c.column) else null end as txn_rate,
       case when (case when a.column = 1 then (b.column - c.column) else null end) is not null then 1 
       else null end as txn_rate_flag

FROM table1 a

Left Join table2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID
Left Join table3 c
ON a.ID2 = c.ID2
```

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: @Jens - sorry, edited. This is SSMS.

Comment: "*how many times*"" usually involves `COUNT` or its emulation by `SUM`.  I do not see either in your code.

Comment: @PM 77-1 - sorry, I should have made that point clear. I want to get feedback on the efficiency of the flag logic. I'll be summing the flags in a a staging table.

Comment: I would do something like this: `case when (a.column = 1 AND  (b.column - c.column) IS NOT NULL then 1 end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the following

```
    case when (case when a.column = 1 then (b.column - c.column) else null end) is not null then 1 
           else null end as txn_rate_flag
```

as `case when a.column = 1 and (b.column - c.column) is not null then 1 else null as txn_rate_flag`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to sum the flags then move the condition `a.column = 1` to a `WHERE` clause and check `b.column - c.column` if it is `NULL` or not (it is possible in a `LEFT JOIN`) in a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN (b.column - c.column) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_flags
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 c ON a.ID2 = c.ID2
WHERE a.column = 1
```